# Large File upload to server throws POCO::Net::NoMessageException using Poco library in C++

Tags: c++, node.js, file-upload, poco, large-files

I'm uploading file using POCO Library in C++ to a NodeJS server. I'm using code from this question to upload file - [POCO C++ simple form submit sample not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21588156/poco-c-simple-form-submit-sample-not-working).

Files of smaller size like 4-5Mb are uploaded successfully but my image file of around 14MB doesnt get uploaded. It takes the complete time to upload the image and then throws exception saying Poco::Net::NoMessageException in my receiveResponse statement. I tried uploading the image to the server using html form and it works perfectly so seems like server side is good. Don't know what else to do with POCO.

Comment: POCO isn't mature enough for serious use (or well designed/implemented). Avoid it.

Comment: Which library would be better for HTTP requests and file uploads in C++ ? Mainly I have to access my rest APIs from c++.

Comment: libcurl is the most mature cross-platform library for this